# Alert not working while Sending mail in php

Tags: jquery, php

I have developed a simple php application. This application contains one html file and one php file. What i am doing is when user selects two dates and enters his/her email addresss, i am calling my php file which is sending the mail to entered email id.

It sends the mail correctly. But the problem is its not showing me the status whether mail is sent or not. I am using alert.

This is my html file :

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
        <label>Leave Application</label><br/>
    From <input id="date" type="text"  name="ndate" /><div id="d1"></div><br/>
        To <input id="date1" type="text"  name="ndate1" /><div id="d2"></div><br/>
        Email To <input type="text" id="UserEmail" name="userEmail" onkeyup=""/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Send" onclick="" />


    <span id="d"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#date").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'Images/icon_cal.png' });
                        $("#date1").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'Images/icon_cal.png' });
        });

                 $("#btn_submit").click(function(event){

                     var hasError = false;
                        var dt1=$("#date").val();
                     var dt2=$("#date1").val();
                     var em=$("#UserEmail").val();
                     $(".error").hide();

                      if(dt1 == '')
                          {
                            $("#d1").before('<span class="error"><font color="red">This Field Must not be empty.</font></span>');
                            hasError = true;
                           }

                        if(dt2 == '')
                        {
                            $("#d2").before('<span class="error"><font color="red">This Field Must not be empty.</font></span>');
                            hasError = true;
                        }

                        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

                        var emailaddressVal = $("#UserEmail").val();

                        if(emailaddressVal == '') {
                            $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error"><font color="red">Please enter your email address.</font></span>');
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                        else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {
                            $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error"><font color="red">Enter a valid email address.</font></span>');
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                        if(hasError == true) { return false; }

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://www.myserver.com/sent_mail.php",                        
                        async: false,
                        data: "dt1="+dt1+"&dt2="+dt2+"&email="+em,
                        success: function(msg){
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                    });                    
                 });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file :

```
   <?php
`extract($_GET);`

        $msg="Respected Sir,\n\n\tI will not be able to come to office from ".$dt1." to ".$dt2.". Please grant my leave";

        $pcto=$email;
        $pcsubject = 'Leave Application';
        $pcmessage = $msg;
        $pcheaders = 'From:abc@abc.com'."\r\n" .
                     'Reply-To: abc@abc.com'."\r\n" .
                     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $isdone=mail($pcto, $pcsubject, $pcmessage, $pcheaders);

        if($isdone)
            echo "Mail Sent";
        else
            echo "Please Try Again";
?>
```

Comment: If you're using Firefox, get the Firebug addon so you can see what the AJAX call returns.

Comment: I am using Firebug. In script panel of firebug i am getting the response. But i dont know its not alerting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know the same code is running for me now...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your script returns the right HTTP status (so the `success` function is actually called)? Try adding

```
error: function(){
    alert('Error');
}
```

to the ajax object to find out (or use FireBug).

Comment: Does it work in a different browser? I'm thinking you may have disabled alerts by mistake when the page alerted you a lot.

Comment: If it sends the email I guess the ajax request is made successfully and will not return an error

Comment: but that php file is returning something. When i add a statement 
$isdone=true;  and run it locally its working.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the if statement like this

```
if(mail($pcto, $pcsubject, $pcmessage, $pcheaders)):
    echo "Mail Sent";
else:
    echo "Please Try Again";
endif;
```

anyway did you try to just echo something in that file?

just add something like this at the top of the file

```
echo "this is returning somethin";
exit;
```

see if this is returned or not, if not then the problem is in the ajax request.

Also I would use firebug so instead of alert do the following (make sure you have the firebug console open and enabled)

```
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: I am getting the response string from that php code. and it is shown in firebug console. I dont know why alert is not working.

Comment: any reason why you disable asynchronous? you have set async: false. What happens when you remove it?